# Copy an Oracle table with indexes but without data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a copy of a table in Oracle and include indexes but I don't want to copy the data.  What's the best way?

Comment: use Toad and extract the DDL script.  Then run that script in the instance you want to create the table (and change what you want/need, tablespace, table name, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to extract the create statements for tables and indexes:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can use the exp command with the ROWS parameter set to N.

Something like

```
exp scott/tiger ROWS=N
```

will do all the tables for that user, you can narrow it down with the TABLES option. Use

```
exp help=yes
```

for all the options.

Answer (score 4):

You could use expdp:

```
expdp tables=table1,table2 content=metadata_only ...
```

[bit.ly/pnLPNz](http://bit.ly/pnLPNz)